# How can I change the value of GPIO4 form 0 to 1?

Tags: gpio

I want to change the value of GPIO4 form 0 to 1. But I can't. The procedure of my typing is below~ 
Please help me. My hardware is Raspberrypi 3 B+ model.

==========================================================================
[image]

Comment: There is no attached circuit to raspberry-pi.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the 1-wire bus is enabled and is using the default GPIO 4.  That could lead to the symptoms you are seeing.

Check that any entries starting w1 are commented out in **/boot/config.txt** and check that the interface is disabled with (sudo) **raspi-config**.

Comment: Thank you for  your kind answer.  But 1-Wire status is disable mode now...

Comment: @son If the answer does not help you should untick it and wait for a proper answer.